# Mysql how to do this without locking

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, sqlperformance

I want to query one table to see whether there exist any rows with 'A' type. 
so I use this sql:

```
SELECT EXISTS(select * from %T where type = 'A');
```

then I need to update another table's column value to the above result. In order to prevent an insert with 'A' type happen during update, I am thinking to use a lock. but lock is very expensive, is there other alternative way to do this without locking?

If we have to use lock, I am thinking if table has already had type A, there is no need to lock insert during update because the result will still be 1. only prevent insert when there is no row with type A. How to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "Transaction" in SQL? I think you can use that. This link will help you "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html"

Comment: Can't you just UPDATE another_table SET field=(SELECT EXISTS...)?

Comment: Certainly any lock is less expensive than doing an update.  What is your actual objective?  What you might want instead of fooling with explicit locking is [`start transaction` ...  `commit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to update a table when there is a type 'A', normally I would suggest you do the update or check every time right after inserting or deleting a row.

Or you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.type = t2.type
SET t1.column1 = 1
WHERE t2.type IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.column1 = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM table2
    WHERE type = 'A'
);
```

Please give me more details such as what is your table like and what exactly you want to do so we can discuss further.

Comment: Thanks! If I use UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.column1 = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM table2
    WHERE type = 'A'
);  will insert with type='A' to table2 be allowed during update?